# Solr search German words

Tags: solr4

I have a problem with German words. Solr (version 4.0.0) tokenzie word Kälte into two wrong tokens. Maybe I have wrong definition of german text field.

Definition of field is below.

```
<fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">

<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" format="snowball" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2"/>
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" format="snowball" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2"/>

  </analyzer>
```

Debug query:

```
<str name="parsedquery">text_de:kã text_de:lte</str><str name="parsedquery_toString">text_de:kã text_de:lte</str>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Tomcat as you application container, you can try to modify server.xml file at AJP/1.3 Connector and add URIEncoding="UTF8". I have found this [Solution](http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Solr_-_configuration_for_Chinese_and_correct_results_for_german_umlauts).